# Powershell - List subscriptions of a specific management group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

On Azure and with Powershell, I need to list all the subscriptions that are in a specific management group.
The command Get-AzSubscription has no parameter to filter on a specific management group. And there is no powershell command (AzManagementGroup) either to list the subscriptions inside.

I was thinking about creating an msgraph query to do that and call it from powershell, but perhaps there is an easier way to do that? :)

Answer (score 3):

The PowerShell Cmdlet you would want to use is [`Get-AzManagementGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azmanagementgroup?view=azps-5.6.0). This is how you would use it:

```
$response = Get-AzManagementGroup -GroupName TestGroupParent -Expand -Recurse
```

Child subscriptions and management groups can be accessed via `Children` property. Something like:

```
$response.Children[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to, recursively, fetch the subscriptions under a given management group is the following:

```
Search-AzGraph -Query "ResourceContainers | where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'" -ManagementGroup $managementGroupName
```

The code above expects the `$managementGroupName` variable to contain the name of the management group

Answer (score 1):

```
Search-AzGraph -Query "ResourceContainers `
   | where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'" -ManagementGroup $managementGroupName -First 200 `
   | Format-Table -Property *
```

The query was good but AZGraph limits you to first 100 results only, so I just changed it a bit to include first 200 results instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it with a PowerShell without the Graph call:

```
$topLvlMgmtGrp = "CHANGETHIS"          # Name of the top level management group
$subscriptions = @()                   # Output array

# Collect data from managementgroups
$mgmtGroups = Get-AzManagementGroup -GroupId $topLvlMgmtGrp -Expand -Recurse

$children = $true
while ($children) {
    $children = $false
    $firstrun = $true
    foreach ($entry in $mgmtGroups) {
        if ($firstrun) {Clear-Variable mgmtGroups ; $firstrun = $false}
        if ($entry.Children.length -gt 0) {
            # Add management group to data that is being looped throught
            $children       = $true
            $mgmtGroups    += $entry.Children
        }
        elseif ($entry.type -ne "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups") {
            # Add subscription to output object
            $subscriptions += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property ([ordered]@{'DisplayName'=$entry.DisplayName;'SubscriptionID'=$entry.Name})
        }
    }
}

$subscriptions
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get all Subscriptions right under a specific Azure Management Group:

```
Get-AzManagementGroupSubscription -GroupName "TestGroup"
```

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azmanagementgroupsubscription?view=azps-9.4.0